# Run node script with a global variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path, ln

I have a node script `index.js` with a node_modules folder.

```
/script/myTestJscript/index.js
/script/myTestJscript/node_modules
/script/myTestJscript/package.json
```

I could run the script with the command `./index.js`

How can I make the script run whith a global command, for example running the script by calling the command `mytestscript` in the console?

I tried to use `sudo ln -s ./script/myTestJscript/index.js mytestscript` but this is not working

Comment: Need more information about how it’s not working. Got some error messages?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to be in that directory, depending on how the index.js program requires other things. I'd use a function:

```bsh
mytestscript() {
    cd /path/to/myTestJscript && ./index.js
}
```

You can save that in your `~/.bashrc`